# IOS p12 file rejected by parse.com - certificate expired

Tags: ios, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications, push

My `Push certificate` expired on `Parse.com`. This is how I generated a new one:

1. I went to the apple developer center and to my `AppId`.
2. I clicked on it, clicked to `Edit` and `Create Certificate`.
3. I downloaded the `.cer` file, double clicked on it and went to my `Keychain Access`, where I exported the `.p12` file.
4. Then I went to my `Parse.com` app settings > `Apple Push Certificates`, and uploaded the `Certificates.p12` file.

From everything I can see this should work. But the site rejects it as `expired`.

I tried renaming the `.p12` file to `appname.p12` but that didn't help.

What am I missing?

Comment: Obviously you are missing a valid .p12 file

Comment: Yeah, but what in my steps are wrong? The expiration date on my .cer file in July 29, 2016. So why is the .p12 expired?

Comment: Try to redownload the cer sometimes it just doesn't refresh well

Comment: Redoing it about 12 times finally worked. What bs this is.

Comment: You didn't have to completely redo, just make it once and then to wait for couple hours...

Comment: BTW There is a reason it called p12 ;-)